Visual Studio inserts brackets around selection
If in the Visual Studio text editor I press <, { or ( to overwrite the selected text, it surrounds it instead. How could I disable it?
C++ option for surrounding text is turned off (Text Editor | C/C++ | Advanced), as well as Text Editor's to automatically insert closing brackets.
I've selected some text and wanted to overwrite it with <. When I press <, the text is surrounded with <>
demo 

Have you tried uncheck the "automatically surround selections when typing quotes or brackets" in options-Text Editor-General?
if this does not work then you may try change the .editorconfig file.

Yes, the option was unchecked.
I don't have .editorconfig file in my project.
This happens even when no project is loaded.

After my testing,Change Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced and set Auto Surround Mode to Never and uncheck "A
utomatically surround selections when typing quotes or brackets" worked for me for a plain text file.

For me it works for C++ Editor, but doesn't affect Text Editor.

Then I'll suggest a full reset of your VS installation as I have tested on a plain text file without any project opened...
